# C# Multiple Input and Output to a Single CMD Process

Tags: c#, process, system.diagnostics

Hi how do i enter a command to a cmd process which is already started by my application and also to redirect the output back. After that i want to enter my input again.

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
            psi.CreateNoWindow = false;
            psi.FileName = "cmd.exe";
            psi.Arguments = "/k";
            psi.UseShellExecute = false;
            psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            psi.RedirectStandardInput = true;
            Process p = new Process();
            p.StartInfo = psi;            
            p.Start();


            while(true)
            {
                p.StandardInput.WriteLine(Console.ReadLine());


                Console.WriteLine(p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());

            }

            Console.Read();

        }
```